# How do I set the right coordinates of a polygon, extracted from a raster image?

Tags: python, gis, raster, analysis

I am trying to create a polygon feature which represents all of the cells in a raster image that have a value over a certain amount, using Python. The problem is that my output feature ends up at the so-called "Null island" (in the Atlantic Ocean), which is a sign of a problem with the coordinate systems. This is a sample of the code I used lastly:

```py
import arcpy
import numpy as np

# Set the ArcGIS Pro project path
arcpy.env.workspace = r"Set the GDB"

# Path to the input TIFF raster 
input_raster = r"path to tiff file"

# Threshold value to create polygons (change as needed)
threshold_value = 40

output_shapefile = "set a name for the output file"

# Check out the Spatial Analyst extension
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Convert raster to NumPy array
raster_array = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(input_raster)

# Create a list to store polygon geometries
polygon_geometries = []

# Get the cell size of the raster
cell_size = arcpy.Raster(input_raster).meanCellWidth

# Get the spatial reference of the raster
raster_spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(input_raster).spatialReference

# Iterate through each cell in the raster
rows, cols = np.where(raster_array > threshold_value)
for row, col in zip(rows, cols):
    x = col * cell_size + 0.5 * cell_size
    y = row * cell_size + 0.5 * cell_size
    vertex_list = [
        arcpy.Point(x - 0.5 * cell_size, y - 0.5 * cell_size),
        arcpy.Point(x - 0.5 * cell_size, y + 0.5 * cell_size),
        arcpy.Point(x + 0.5 * cell_size, y + 0.5 * cell_size),
        arcpy.Point(x + 0.5 * cell_size, y - 0.5 * cell_size),
        arcpy.Point(x - 0.5 * cell_size, y - 0.5 * cell_size)
    ]
    polygon = arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array(vertex_list))
    polygon_geometries.append(polygon)

# Create the output shapefile
output_shapefile = arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(
    arcpy.env.workspace,
    output_shapefile,
    "POLYGON",
    spatial_reference=raster_spatial_ref
)

# Add a field to store the values of each cell (optional)
arcpy.management.AddField(output_shapefile, "CellValue", "DOUBLE")

# Insert the polygons into the feature class
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(output_shapefile, ["SHAPE@", "CellValue"]) as cursor:
    for polygon in polygon_geometries:
        cursor.insertRow([polygon, threshold_value])

print("Polygon creation completed.")
```

So far, I checked the properties of each layer: geaodatabase, datasets, input feature, output feature (after the code was run) and the Map tab that I'm working on and all of their coordinate systems are the same. It doesn't make sense to me why the output layer will not get the correct coordinates. I am using ArcGIS Pro as my main GIS software.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am trying to accomplish the exact same thing.

Comment: No, I stopped trying at one point..